# prove the existence, and find, the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$

Tags: calculus, analysis

for the sequence $a_n$ where $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1} = 2+ \frac{1}{1+a_n} \ \forall n \in \ \mathbb{N}$

prove the existence, and find, the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$

Well, here's how I solved the problem so I am looking for a good critique and some suggestions.

first, I listed the first four terms of the sequence:

$a_2 = 2+ \frac{1}{1+1}= \frac{5}{2},
a_3 = 2+ \frac{1}{1+\frac{5}{2}}= \frac{16}{7}, 
a_4 = 2+ \frac{1}{1+\frac{16}{7}}= \frac{53}{23}$

now note that $a_1 < a_2$ and now assume that $a_k < a_{k+1}$ and we can have $a_{k+1}<a_{k+2}$ so the sequence is increasing by induction.

Now, we need to show that this sequence is bounded.

Take 10 as the bounding limit, and note $a_1<10$ $\Rightarrow$ $2+\frac{1}{11} < 10$

so the sequence is bounded above $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ by 10.

Now, we can have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = A$

so, $A = 2+\frac{1}{1+A} \Rightarrow $

$A(A+1) = 2(1+A) + 1 \Rightarrow$
$A^2+A = 3+2A \Rightarrow A^2-A-3=0 \Rightarrow $
$A=\frac{1+\sqrt13}{2}$

Comment: The sequence is not increasing. Proof is not given that it is increasing (and cannot be).

Comment: You could consider alternating odd and even subsequences and see if they are increasing/decreasing or neither...

Comment: yes, the sequence is actually decreasing so probably I just need to remove the first part of the proof. However, I end up with the correct limit value

Comment: Note that, this is a continued fraction.